# Finding a way to use PIMPL with external constant definitions for the size of an array inside the implementation

Tags: c++, linker, pimpl-idiom

We have the following situation: We are using a processor which has defined sections inside its RAM, which must be used by a special implementation using the PIMPL-Principle. For example the private Implementation would look like this:

```
Impl( )
{
public:
  void doSomething()
  {
    for( uint32_t i = 0; i < DATA_SIZE; ++i )
    {
      // do stuff with buf[i]
    }
  }
private:
  
  static uint8_t  buf[DATA_SIZE] __attribute__ ((section("data_buffer"), aligned (8)));
};
```

As you see DATA_SIZE is not defined here. The point here is that we can use the processor-vendor-provided functions inside the Impl on different processors of the same vendor with different Linkerscripts defining the section "data_buffer". This is possible because the used underlying system provides the same functions for different processors of the same family.
But it must be a PIMPL to guarantee that if I change to a different processor of another vendor, we can use another Impl for the other vendor.
So it can happen someone is using the section with a different DATA_SIZE because he defines his sections in a different manner in his project (even on the same processor).
The initialization and everything will be of course done via the constructor etc.

But is it possible to make the DATA_SIZE settable and not to define it directly in the Impl-File?

As I know of the PIMPL the target is to compile it and to have a defined ABI, which for me means that the compiled file can't change in size afterwards when linking. Is my thought right? (for me it is for now only to quickly change the implementation and never touch the upper laying PIMPL-using software-part, but we will use a "pimpl-library" in the future, where we want to just change the compiled Impl-files.)

I wanted to prevent the usage of a Base-/Interface-Class from which you derive to fully hide the implementation to the developer and not passing any references or pointers of the derived class because this will need a software change in the upper layers.

Thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Have you considered just using a #define?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But is it possible to make the DATA_SIZE settable and not to define it directly in the Impl-File?

The size of a non-static member array must be set in the class definition.

You can include the value from elsewhere using the pre-processor, so it doesn't have to be "in the file" in that sense, but what ever that size is, it must match across all TU and changing the size only inside the private implementation without modifying the clients of the interface is not possible..

---

Note that as long as you define the array to be at least the size and alignment of a pointer, then you can have any data in the private implementation using indirection - by storing a pointer and creating the concrete object in dynamic storage.

Comment: I switched the buf to static, because else it won't compile anyways, because the attribute "section" can't be used there. Just forgot to write it down properly. But doesn't the array needs to be defined with its size when it uses the section-attribute?
Could I maybe define this array in a different file and just pass the pointer to it to the impl-class? So we can have different "impls" for the arrays at least, which then will be included in the Impl. The build-system would then choose the correct file to include there, means to link to the array with the defined DATA_SIZE there.

Comment: @NetoBF I don't know about "section-attribute". It's non-standard. See what the manual of whatever compiler provides the language extension says.

Comment: @NetoBF It's unclear what you mean by "impl-class". Impl is short for "implementation", which is what is kept Private in PIMPL. So, are you talking about the class named `Impl` which isn't the implementation, or the implementation which isn't the class named `Impl`? `for the arrays at least ...` If you define the array to be a static member, then there is one array, not many.

Comment: sorry for the confusion.
section is special to ARM: https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0491/f/Compiler-specific-Features/--attribute----section--name-----variable-attribute
the "impl-class" is the ```Impl``` from my example. So it is the private implementation, yes. I just did not write the outer class here, I will clearify it in the question. I use more than one array for me, I just placed one here for the example.

Comment: So you brought me to that idea with the pointer. If I place separate folders next to the Impl.cpp, let's say "proc1", "proc2".. etc. and everyone contains the same named header file, e.g. "sections.hpp", which then contains the ```DATA_SIZE``` and the array as static. Then the Impl.cpp will include the header "sections.hpp" and does not use the array directly but a pointer to it. So I can then define by my build-system which folder to take to include its contained "sections.hpp"-header when linking. This should not break the PIMPL, right?